# Power BI API returns 0 workspaces

Tags: api, pdf, powerbi, export

Power BI API returns 0 workspaces

I try to get report in PDF using API. The simple client written in C# stops on getting workspaces. Unfortunately it returns 0 workspaces. The fragment of my code is as follows. The function which gives me workspaces is pbiClient.Groups.GetGroups().Value.

```
public static Group GetWorkspace(string WorkspaceName) {
      var workspaces = pbiClient.Groups.GetGroups().Value;
      foreach (var workspace in workspaces) {
        if (workspace.Name.Equals(WorkspaceName))
          return workspace;
      }
      return null;
    }
```

I have provided correct public-application-id, redirect-uri, tenant-name, confidential-application-id and confidential-application-secret. Application is registered in Azure.

Comment: This method will return only the workspaces, in which the user/service principal used to acquire the token is a member. Otherwise you will have to use some admin API to get a list of workspaces.

Comment: Thanks Andrey. You mean pbiClient.Groups.GetGroupsAsAdmin() ?

Comment: Yes, GetGroupsAsAdmin can be used to return list of workspaces, including deleted ones, personal workspaces of other users, etc.

Comment: Got "Unauthorized" exception after use GetGroupsAsAdmin